# RichTextBox Default Value?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, richtextbox

Is there any property to I define the default value in richtextbox?

I mean, by default the text is like this: "Type what you want", and when the user clicks, this word dissapear.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A RichTextBox contains a FlowDocument.  You have to add a FlowDocument of some kind to the RichTextBox in order to get default text in the document.

To get the text to disappear when you click on it, simply handle the GotFocus event, and reset the FlowDocument.

Try doing something like this:

```
<RichTextBox GotFocus="RichTextBox_GotFocus">
    <RichTextBox.Document>
        <FlowDocument>
            <FlowDocument.Blocks>
                <Paragraph>
                    Type what you want
                </Paragraph>
            </FlowDocument.Blocks>
        </FlowDocument>
    </RichTextBox.Document>
</RichTextBox>
```

And in the .cs file:

```
private void RichTextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ((RichTextBox)sender).Document = new FlowDocument();
}
```

Comment: its not that simple. This way, always when the richtextbox get focus, all the text will be lost.

Comment: Isn't that what you asked for?  "I mean, by default the text is like this: "Type what you want", and when the user clicks, this word dissapear."  If you don't want all the text to disappear, then don't handle the GotFocus event.